# Can't "touch" file from argument containing a period

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make a shells script that makes making a config file for qemu-launcher (the only qemu GUI out of 4 that I tried that worked for me) a one-step process, but cannot figure out how to pass a command line argument to the "touch" command.

My console input is `config hello.iso`.

My script so far is:

```
#!/bin/sh

touch $1
```

Which does not create a file. I've tried making a variable that equals `$1`, then using that, but I still get no response. I've tried `$1` in both double and single quotes; with double I get nothing, and with single the resulting filename is `1`.

However, if I pass the argument of just `hello`, then the file with that name is created, but I need the extension for use with other things.

Is it not possible to do this? Or am I just not understanding it?

What I really want to do is take the argument and remove the `.iso` from it, then use that as the filename, but I'm pretty sure I can do that using a grep positive lookahead.

Comment: your script worked for me in cygwin Windows XP. Dot is passed

Comment: I am using the latest Linux Mint.

Comment: What happens if you instead do `touch "$1"` (note the quotes.) If that won't work either, then try `touch -- "$1"`. And if that won't work, then please use `echo "$1"` instead and post the output here.

Comment: I said in my first post that with double quotes no file is created. Adding the double dashes does nothing. Both `echo $1` and `echo "$1"` echo `hello.iso`.

Comment: Weird. Are you sure you're calling the correct script? Is it in your $PATH environment variable? (I assume you've put it in a directory in $PATH since you're calling it with `config hello.iso` instead of `./config hello.iso`.) What's the output of `which config`?

Comment: Also, when replying to comments, use the @username notation, otherwise people have no idea that you replied to them, as they don't get a notification. I only noticed your reply because I happened to have this page still open in my browser.

Comment: @NikosC. Will do! Yes, I put it in /usr/local/bin, so I can call it from multiple directories without having to use long path names or copy and pasting it many times. `which config` gives the correct result of `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Does it print any error? like `permission denied`?

Comment: @anishsane It does not. I used `sudo chmod 0777` on it to make sure that I had all necessary permissions. Maybe overkill, but it's not likely to mess anything up. :)

Comment: Maybe you have another `config` in your path, use `type -a config` to see all of them and which is first.

Comment: @Kevin The one I made is the only one that comes up. I think I'm just going to use a script that lets me run an ISO in Qemu in the same directory. It's much simpler than dealing with a GUI!

Answer (score 0):

if you use the bash instead of sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

myVar=$1
touch ${myVar%.iso}
```

will do the job. The string following the '%' is stripped off from the end of the content of the variable.
To get more information with your current version of your script, please try the following:

- rename your script - don't use 'config'
- change the 'touch' by a 'echo'
- redirect the output of your script to a file
- look at the content of the output with

  od -a myOutputOfTheScript

or ...
call your script with

bash -x myScript hello.iso > ouput.txt

Answer (score 0):

What you had (the variant with double quotes) is correct.  Changing to `/bin/bash` won't fix this issue, since bash and sh overlap entirely for this syntax:

```
#!/bin/sh

touch "$1"
```

Some things to check/try:

1. Be sure you've turned on execute permission with `chmod +x config`
2. Make sure you run it as `./config hello.iso` if you're in the directory with it, or using its full pathname otherwise, (example only) `/home/your-username/bin/config hello.iso` depending on where you put the script.
3. Try adding a `set -x` above the `touch "$1"` line in the script to see a debugging trace.
4. On a handful of shell implementations (notably csh) the last line of a script will be skipped if it doesn't have a newline on the end.  I usually just add a comment like `#---eof`.  This is unlikely to be a problem in most modern shells.

You may have a system command called `config` already in your path.  Run `type config` to check.  I'd suggest picking a more specific name for the script to lower the odds of this kind of collision.

One you have a working script (probably with a better name), it's typically to put it in a directory named `bin` in your home directory and then insure that directory's name is in your `PATH` environment variable.  Check with `env`, adding missing directories to PATH varies by shell and taste, `~/.bashrc` is the most common place (though technically limited), and `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.profile` are generally better but trickier for new users.  In all of those, `~` refers to your home directory.

A typical PATH:

```
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

What a scripter generally prefers (assuming one named `scripter` here):

```
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/home/scripter/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

This user would have put your `config` script in `/home/scripter/bin/config` - but chosen a different name ;-)